# Using present simple in past context

Tags: present-simple

Is the present simple tense correctly used in this sentence:

> Emily finally decided to live with a rural family because **she always
> has a thing for nature**.

The struggle is that the action (living with a rural family) belongs to the past and Emily's liking for nature is always true and it will never change. Can we use present simple when telling a story of the past?

Answer (score 1):

If Emily is someone you know and you are mentioning something she did in the past, it's fine (but note that *have a thing for* is an informal expression).

If the whole story is set in the past, it would be more appropriate to say **because she had always had a 'thing' for nature** (she had always been interested in/attracted by/drawn to nature).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would say:

As Emily has always had a thing for nature, she decided to live with a rural family.

The present perfect would make it true at the time of speaking as well.